# Wordpress query reverse order

Tags: query-posts, get-posts, order, array

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'etlap', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post__in' => $ids, 'post_status' => 'any', 'orderby' => 'post__in');
```

I want to make the orderby status reversed. How is it possible?

Sorry if I ask stupid question, but I couldn't find any documentary about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `'post__in'` in the `'orderby'` parameter, the `'order'` parameter will have no effect, however, you can simply reverse the array you are passing to `'post__in'`:

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'etlap',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'post__in' => array_reverse($ids),
                'post_status' => 'any',
                'orderby' => 'post__in'
             );
```

Comment: array_reverse doesn't seems working for me :(

Comment: Sorry, it worked, just my posts had bad relase dates.